# How to override ToString method for List of Lists

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty new with C# and I'm stuck on one university exercise. I have to sort some elements and them display them by overriden method ToString. And override is problem there. List works with ToString, List of Lists not.

Untill now I've tried to create some easy foreach and put it into overriden method, still, without success. It works only out of method. Asked my professor and he told me, it's because I'm acessing List, not Lista1, or something like that. Like I've said, I'm newbie.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace lista_7
{
    class Lista
    {
        public static Random rand = new Random();
        public List<int> nums = new List<int> ();

        public Lista(int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                nums.Add(rand.Next(100));
            }
        }

        public Lista()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= rand.Next(5); i++)
            {
                nums.Add(rand.Next(100));
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            String result = "";
            foreach (var numbers in nums)
            {
                result += numbers + " ";
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    class Lista1 : Lista, IComparable<Lista1>
    {
        public Lista1(int n) : base(n) { }
        public Lista1() : base() { }
        public int CompareTo(Lista1 x)
        {
            if (x == this) return 0;
            else if (x == null) return 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.nums.Count && i < x.nums.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this.nums[i] > x.nums[i]) return 1;
                else if (this.nums[i] < x.nums[i]) return -1;
            }

            return x.nums.Count > this.nums.Count ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Lista1> fir = new List<Lista1> { 
              new Lista1(5), 
              new Lista1(), 
              new Lista1(3) 
            };

            foreach (var variable in fir)
            {
                //Console.Write ( toString )
                foreach (var x in variable.nums)
                {
                    Console.Write(x + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fir.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I would describe errors, but I dont have any. fir.ToString shows System.Collections.Generic.List`1[lista_7.Lista1]

Comment: you are using `List<T>` which doesn't override `ToString`

Comment: So I won't be able to use ToString with List<List<int>> ? It worked with List<int>. I'm sorry if my questions are dumb.

Comment: What is the desired output from that particular line?  Do you want it to print out the `ToString()` of each of the three lists inside `fir`?  If so, print them out using a loop.

Comment: Yea, yea. My exercise is to sort lists inside list based on their length then output them like:
1st line: 1 2
2nd line: 1 2 3
3rd line: 1 2 3 4 5 ... Sorry, for formatting, but I'm not sure how it works here. Just each line should contain numbers inside list.

Comment: So, there is no easy way to make it work? I have deadline today. If not, I'm gonna try to repair it later, but won't bother now. Maybe my professor won't kick me.
UPDATE: Seems like someone deleted his message. I'm not talking to myself.

Comment: Does the exercise require that you override `ToString`? If it doesn't then that makes it much easier. You can't override `ToString` without declaring a class in which to override it. That means in order to override it you would have to create a class that inherits from `List<List<int>>`. You can do that, but I don't know if it would make sense just for the sake of being able to override `ToString`.

Comment: Oh yea, thats what my professor told me. Now I remember. That i have to declare new class and override it there. I don't think I'm gonna bother with that. This is too advanced for me. Even this exercise is a lot, it's second exercise from C# and there is already so much OOP. Anyway, thanks for your answers. I wasn't sure if it's really so hard. I would probably stuck on it for next 3 hours (if lucky).

Comment: @AndrewMean In comments, use the backtick (left of 1 on your keyboard) around code to format it as such.

Comment: Please clarify & specify your goal so we can help you achieve it

Comment: @MayerSpitzer answer did what I wanted. Not sure if it's good to do that, but it makes everything. Shows every list in another line.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `fir.ToString()` inside your loop as `variable.ToString()`:

```
foreach (var variable in fir)
{
    Console.WriteLine(variable.ToString());
}
```

*I'm not sure it's a good idea to override `ToString()` method, I'd rather create an extension method for this, but that's about how it should work.*

Comment: That's what I've wanted. What's this sorcery.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, he's requiring you to inherit from a list and override its `ToString()` method, and then inherit from a list of that list and override its `ToString()` method.

First, the inner list (for lack of a better term):

```
public class InnerList : List<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // return the contents of the list somehow formatted as strings.
        return string.Join(" ", this);
    }
}
```

Next, a list *of* that list:

```
public class OuterList : List<InnerList>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        ForEach(inner =>
        {
            if (inner != null) result.AppendLine(inner.ToString());
        });
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

The `ToString()` method of the outer list works by calling the `ToString()` method of all of the lists it contains.

I'm obviously making up what goes in the overridden methods. But this is how you would override them according to the requirements you specified. In "real life" this wouldn't make any sense. We might declare a `List<List<int>>` without creating any new classes, and then write code to render it as a string. We could write code to render the same `List<List<int>>` two different ways. If we do this by overriding `ToString()` it suggests that we would create different inherited classes to format the numbers differently.

(Some courses tend to over-emphasize inheritance. It's useful, but they make it seem like it's the answer to everything.)

Note that there's also no need for either list to populate itself. That just makes it more confusing. You can write separate code to add numbers to it.